Запуск Nginx\ Телеграмм бот
Так выглядит кусок описания того, как должен работать телеграмм бот:
1)Пользователь через приложение Telegram отправляет сообщение (любое) на сервера Telegram;
2)Компонент Telegram Client обращается к серверам Telegram и получает список всех новых сообщений;
3)Компонент Telegram Client достаёт из списка новых сообщений наше (предполагается, что оно первое в списке) затем обрабатываются остальные;
4)Компонент Telegram Client проверяет сообщение пользователя на предусмотренное в боте.
5)Если мы не предусмотрели ответ на такое сообщение, то отвечаем:
Нет такой команды;
6)Если обработчик для сообщения пользователя найден, то Telegram Client перенаправляет запрос компоненту Bot Logic (перед ним сидит компонент Nginx);
7)Nginx перенаправляет запрос одной из рабочих копий компонента Bot Logic;
run.py:
import asyncio
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.fsm.storage.redis import RedisStorage
import redis.asyncio as aioredis

from config import TOKEN, REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT, REDIS_DB
from app.handlers import router
from aiogram.types import Message
from typing import Any, Dict, Callable, Awaitable

class RedisMiddleware:
def __init__(self, redis: aioredis.Redis):
    self.redis = redis
async def __call__(self, handler: Callable[[Message, Dict[str, Any]], Awaitable[Any]], 
event: Message, data: Dict[str, Any]) -> Any:
    data["redis"] = self.redis
    return await handler(event, data)

async def main():
    redis = await aioredis.from_url(f'redis://{REDIS_HOST}:{REDIS_PORT}/{REDIS_DB}')
    bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
    dp = Dispatcher(storage=RedisStorage(redis))
    dp.include_router(router)
    router.message.middleware(RedisMiddleware(redis))

await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Остановка')

handlers.py:
from aiogram import F, Router
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command
from aiogram.types import Message
from redis.asyncio import Redis
from typing import Any

router = Router()

@router.message(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
await message.answer('Старт')

@router.message()
async def _(message: Message, redis: Redis):
   value = await redis.get("TEST")
   if value:
      value_str = value.decode("utf-8")
      await message.answer(value_str)
   else:
      await message.answer('Ключ не найден')

И тут возникают проблемы, а точнее на 6-7 пунктах. Nginx в моём случаи должен работать только как балансировщик нагрузки и вот такую конфигурацию я написал:
upstream bot_servers {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name мой публичный ip;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://bot_servers;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    }
}

Но насколько я понимаю это неправильно, ибо даже с выключенным сервером Nginx бот всё равно работает и отвечает на сообщения(хотя не должен).
И я не знаю всё ли я правильно сделал. Мне кажется у меня кривая конфигурация Nginx, но как её исправить не знаю.
Заранее извиняюсь за кривое написание вопроса.

Непонятно о каких ошибках на 6-7 пунктах вы пишите? И непонятно для чего у вас такая конструкция, зачем вам редис и нжинкс если вы и так используете aiogram? Цели непонятны, что вы хотите сделать?

Это задание(точнее часть, там много разных пунктов) из ВУЗа и мне их нужно сделать. Практически всë в коде это временные затычки. То что я сделал это неправильно, потому что запросы не проходят через Ndginx, а как сделать нормально я не знаю, поэтому и спрашиваю.

ТГ боты не нуждаются ни в nginx ни в redis, они работают в основном через пулинг. В вашем случае это так dp.start_polling(bot) - из чего следует, что то что вы нагородили на работу ТГ бота вообще никак не влияет. Если вам нужно показать умение работать с nginx и redis, то лучше вам рассмотреть работу с веб фреймворками

Извиняюсь если это совсем странный вопрос вцелом, но мне дали задание и убрать Nginx я не могу, мне нужно только чтобы он распределял нагрузку, даже если всë это не имеет смысла.

Если читать шаги буквально, то NGINX и не должен стоять перед ТГ клиентом. Он должен быть после него перед несколькими экземплярами Bot Logic. ТГ клиента можно оставить по идее на aiogram, а вот Bot Logic уже писать без него, чтобы ТГ клиент их вызывал только через NGINX. Соответственно, Bot Logic и ТГ клиент - это должны быть разные приложения (контейнеры Docker, как вариант). Иначе непонятно как NGINX можно вставить внутрь цельного приложения.

Добавил схему, да, вы правы,  Nginx вызывает экземпляр Bot logic, но как это реализовать в коде?

Ваш конфиг NGINX выглядит нормально, только соответственно должно быть указано больше экземпляров бота. Например, на портах 8080, 8081, 8082 и т.д. Как реализовать в коде - посмотрите библиотеки для создания API на Python, например FastAPI, + как это обернуть в докер. Попалась на глаза такая статья - https://habr.com/ru/companies/domclick/articles/548610/ Очень похоже на то что Вам надо

То есть с помощью FastAPI Вы сделаете свой локальный API для Bot logic, чтобы ТГ клиент по нему вызывал полезные действия. И обращаться он всегда будет к одному хосту, по типу http://localblabla:80, а вот за ним уже будут несколько одинаковых контейнеров, между которыми и будет распределяться нагрузка.

Понял, попробую разобраться, спасибо

Могу ошибаться, но по идее, в Bot logic можно сделать 1-к-1 API методы - дублирующие хендлеры в ТГ клиенте. Цепочка обработки будет какой-то такой: пользователь пишет send_cat -> реагирует хендлер ТГ клиента send_cat -> из него вызов http://localblabla:80/api/v1/send_cat -> NGINX перенаправляет на экземпляр бота -> в экземпляре Bot Logic отрабатывает API /send_cat

А нужно будет выкупать статический ip?

По идее нет - для работы с ТГ внешний IP не нужен, а остальное находится внутри сети. Когда идёт речь про API имейте ввиду, что всё это может работать и во внутренней сети, даже в рамках одной машины. Это просто способ связать между собой сервисы.
